# SQL запрос на выборку из таблицы с категориями и подкатегориями

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос, выборка, связи

Есть таблица Category и таблица Item.

Структура таблицы Category:

```
- id
- title
- parent_id
```

Структура таблицы Item:

```
- id
- title
- is_active (0 или 1)
- category_id
```

Таблицы связаны по полю category_id связью 1 ко многим. Т.е. 1 категория может иметь много itemoв.

В таблице Category двухуровневая иерархия, т.е. таким образом идёт разбивка на основные категории и подкатегории.
Категории это те записи, в которых parent_id = NULL. А подкатегории, это те записи у которых parent_id =  какому-то id.

Один Item может принадлежать как основной категории(где parent_id = null) так и подкатегории(дочерней).
Item может быть активный и не активный ( 0 или 1).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать запрос и выбрать из таблицы Category все основные категории(у которых parent_id = null), которые имеют активные itemы (is_active = 1) и которые имеют подкатегории так же с активными iteмами.
Т.е. если в дочерней подкатегории есть itemы c is_active = 0, тогда данную категорию не выводить. 
Я смог только выбрать основные категории, в которых есть активные элементы:

```
SELECT categories.title, count(analyses.id) FROM items
            INNER JOIN categories on items.category_id = categories.id
            WHERE categories.parent_id IS NULL
            AND categories.is_active = 1
            GROUP BY analyses.category_id
            ORDER BY analyses_categories.title
```

Но с подкатегориями справиться уже не могу, подскажите пожалуйста у кого опыта побольше.

Comment: Как сюда Jquery попал?

Comment: хотел написать query))

Comment: ЯННП. Если у категории есть И активные, И неактивные - выводить или нет? А если у неё есть в подкатегориях И активные, И неактивные - выводить или нет? Отнеситесь аккуратнее к формулированию требований и исправьте вопрос.

Comment: Вывести категорию, в которой:
1) есть активные items
2) есть подкатегории, в которых активные items
А где я не правильно вопрос сформулировал?

Comment: для начала попробуйте добавить в условия `and exists(select 1 from categories c1, items i1 where c1.parent_id=categories.id and i1.category_id=c1.id)` оно проверит наличие подходящих подкатегорий. Разумеется это ни как не скажется на том количестве, которое вы выбираете.